# Replacing HTML tags using VISUAL MODE in VIM

Tags: html, vim

so I can replace "<" -square brackets in VIM using ":s/</</g" and thats great, but It does not replace the ending bracket, thats problem number one. But the main issue is:

How do I replace all square brackets marked in VISUAL MODE? Say I want to replace all marked brackets "

just as on the screenshot with "&lt", so It will be displayed in HTML as code[image]. I want to replace only them, not the others, do you know what is the pattern?

Sorry for beginners question, but I would like to know.

Thank you so much

Comment: It works in VISUAL MODE, but the escaping character exits the VISUALLY SELECTED LINES I think...

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

1. Those are *angle brackets*, not "square brackets".
2. `:s/</</g` does nothing useful. Did you mean `:s/</\&lt;/g`?
3. You already know how to change the *opening* bracket so you only need to do the same thing for the *closing* bracket but with the appropriate pattern and replacement.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly interpret your question and screenshot, you want the `>` marked in red to be replaced with `&gt;` -- yes?  If so, then I think @romainl suggested a good answer:

`:s/>/&gt;/g`

Answer (score 0):

:s/>/>/g is working fine, thank you.

Basically, I also wanted to know if I can do this for multiple lines. Bat all you need to do is to select or mark specific "angle brackets", so again, thanks to romainnl and m_mlvx.